# How to pass multiple parameters in AGAINST command in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure containing 2 different input parameters.

```
p_first_name with datatype VARCHAR(15)
p_last_name with datatype VARCHAR(15)
```

I am using the following query in my stored procedure:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM student_names
WHERE CASE WHEN p_first_name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE first_name LIKE CONCAT('%',p_first_name,'%') END
AND CASE WHEN p_last_name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE last_name LIKE CONCAT('%',p_last_name,'%') END;
```

When I execute my procedure call, it works but takes too much time to execute due to LIKE operator.

I need to replace it with MATCH and AGAINST commands.

I want the statement something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM student_names
WHERE CASE WHEN p_first_name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE MATCH(first_name) AGAINST(p_first_name) END
AND CASE WHEN p_last_name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE MATCH(last_name) AGAINST(p_last_name) END;
```

But an error gets generated when I try to execute it. According to the MySQL Documentation, the query should be something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM student_names
WHERE MATCH(first_name,last_name) AGAINST(p_first_name,p_last_name) END;
```

But I need to apply with CASE statements for both parameters.

How to do? Thanks!

I tried to optimize my stored procedure. But got stuck due to error. Keeping in mind the FULLTEXT index was already created.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_first_last_name ON student_names(first_name,last_name);
```